# How to check for a projective space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

[image: From a notes of Harvard (Foundations of Projective Geometry)]

When I have a division ring commutative its pretty straight forward!
But when its not commutative then I'm stuck, it's possible that in this case its not a projective plane?

Can someone give a counterexample?

[image: This are the axioms]

Comment: How do the axioms P1, P2, P3, P4 read?

Comment: This has nothing to do with commutivity. What do your equivalence classes look like? How about your lines? You should be able to prove this with a straight forward application of the definitions.

Comment: This is true for all division rings, not just fields. Where do you get stuck in checking the axioms? Where do you think you're using commutativity?

Comment: It has for example to show that the line is unique I use the normal given for the product cross between 2 points but then I can not check this line verify the that the points belong to $x.n =0$ because I don't have commutativity

Comment: I find how to check for P3, P4 but not for P1 or P2. Any help!